# Azure Ad B2C for flutter

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

Is there any efficient way to implement Azure Ad B2C in flutter for android , ios and web??
Currently I have figured out a solution for android and ios by using flutter_webview_plugin but it doesn't work for flutter web.

Comment: Did you happen to check this https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-azure-authentication-with-ad-b2c-8b76c81dd48e

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `flutter_azure_b2c` package to implement Azure AD B2C on android and web but the limitation here is it’s not available for ios yet.

Or You can use `flutter_appauth` which is available for android and ios.

**Note:** For now there is no package which can be used to implement for all the 3 platforms.

**Reference:**

[flutter_azure_b2c - Dart API docs (pub.dev)](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_azure_b2c)

[Flutter + Azure : Authentication with AD B2C | by Jayesh | Flutter Community | Medium](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-azure-authentication-with-ad-b2c-8b76c81dd48e)

Comment: Yes got it . For android and ios im using webview and however my web app is being built as an independent project im using flutter_azure_b2c for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flutter_azure_b2c: ^0.0.8` that is available for all platform of `web`, `android` and `ios`.

Comment: Yes, it (might) work on all three, but it is missing a lot of features, actually (v 0.0.9), it is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aad_oauth: ^0.4.4` which is available for `Web`, `Android` and `iOS`.

Package Link: https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth